# PivotTables - having DateStart and DateEnd in data - Show 1 for all days between the dates

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have a problem with showing certain data in my pivot table in excel. Let's say that in the data I have, there are columns of Organization, PromotionName, DateStart, DateEnd.
From this data i need to create a Pivot table where in the RowRange I have Organizations and in the Columns I have all 365 days of the year. In the DataBodyRange I need to have 1 for each day the certain promotion was active (and it would show 2 for that day if two promotions were active at the same time and so on).

This is how it should look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHu9H.png

On this screen, In Selgros there was only one promotion active that started on February 2nd and ended on February 15th.

Data record would look like this:

**Organization**   /  **PromotionName**  /   **DateStart**   /  **DateEnd**
Selgros     /     Promo1      /      02.02.2016  /  15.02.2016

Does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you will need an extra field in your data with the date for a specific day.
in your example you will need 16 rows, starting with 02.02.2016, 03.02.2016, .... , 15.02.2016.
you can easily create these rcords by code or SQL

Comment: I was considering this, but I was hoping to do it without increasing the number of rows in ma data :( like by adding one or two columns or through pivottable itself

Comment: maybe this is possible with powerpivot, but with the "normal" pivot in Excel this is not possible (unless someone proves me wrong)

Comment: Ok, maybe someone will, but thanks for the answer though